# Import a module in web worker in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app, web-worker

i have the following code in `worker.js` and i am trying to import KMeans inside of it, and i export the worker as shown.

```
import KMeans from "tf-kmeans";

const splitText = () => {
  ...
    const kmeans = new KMeans({});
  ...
  };
};

let code = splitText.toString();
code = code.substring(code.indexOf("{") + 1, code.lastIndexOf("}"));

const blob = new Blob([code], { type: "application/javascript" });
const worker_script = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

export default worker_script;
```

In the main component where i want to call the worker, i call it using the following:

```
let worker = new Worker(new URL(worker_script, import.meta.url), {
      type: "module",
    });
```

but when i use the worker i get the following error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: tf_kmeans__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1___default is not defined
```

How can this be solved? TIA

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out using [worker-loader](https://v4.webpack.js.org/loaders/worker-loader/).
Implement your `worker.js` as the following:

```
import KMeans from "tf-kmeans";

onmessage = function (event) {
  // worker body
  //self.postMessage(resultToReturn);
};
```

then in your main component

1. import the Worker using worker loader using the following: `import Worker from "worker-loader!./kmeans.worker.js";`. you may add `// eslint-disable-next-line import/no-webpack-loader-syntax` to avoid linting problems.
2. instantiate the worker: `var worker = new Worker();`
3. To send anything to the worker use: `worker.postMessage({key:value});`
4. To get anything from the worker use: `worker.onmessage = (ev) => {};`